# Do not understand the solution to this orthogonal projection finding question

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation

There are a number of things I do not understand about this solution:

1. How do we know $v-x$ is colinear with the normal vector? In an earlier question, we were given that $x$ is a point in $n$-dimensional space. That is all the information we have for $x$. As far as I can understand, $v$ and $x$ are just two random points in space, so how do we know the vector between them is colinear?
2. So I get that $\lambda$ is the length of the orthogonal projection and $\theta$ gives the direction.But why is $\theta x+\theta_0=0$? It said '$x$ lies in the plane', but again the only info we were given was that $x$ is a point in space, so where does this come from? (In fact what does lying in the plane mean? I get how a point lies on a plane, but not lying in a plane)

Apology for these seemingly amateur questions as I am still trying to learn this stuff.

---

(These come from MITx 6.86x)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) I'm guessing that $x$ is their notation for the projection of $v$ onto the plane $\cal P$. In that case, $v - x$ would be pointing in the normal direction and hence collinear with $\theta$.

(2) Again, now that $x$, the projection of $v$ onto the plane, lies in the plane, it must satisfying the plane's equation: $\theta \cdot x + \theta_0 = 0$.